# Hartshorne Ex I.3.20b proving regular functions over $Y-P$ cannot be extended to $Y$ even if $P$ is normal

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Ex I.3.20b want us to give an example with the properties stated in the title. Many solution that I found online points to the counterexample $f(x)=1/x$ over the affine line with origin removed. But almost all of them are without explanation.

However, when worked on it, it's not that strict forward to show the nonexistence of extension. Here is one of my attempts:

Assume the extension $\tilde{f}$ exists and $\tilde{f}(0)=a\in\mathbb{R}$, show that such extension cannot be continuous.
Consider the spaces with different topologies $\tilde{f}:(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{S})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{Z})$, where $\mathfrak{S}$ is the standard topology and $\mathfrak{Z}$ is the Zariski topology. It suffice if we can show $f$ cannot be continuous under this setting on topology since

$\tilde{f}:(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{S})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{Z})$ is discontinuous at 0 $\Rightarrow$ $\tilde{f}:(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{Z})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{Z})$ is discontinuous at 0. So, discontinuity such function disproved the possibility of extension towards the whole affine line.

But I couldn't show $\tilde{f}:(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{S})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{Z})$ is discontinuous at 0, even if I take $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Any other counterexample or points towards my argument is appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with the affine line minus a point? Even simpler, what is the issue with the projective line minus a point?

Comment: The projective line example is an elegant example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algebraic argument: Assume $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ has an extension $\tilde f$ on $\mathbb A^1_{k}$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. The regular functions on $\mathbb A^1_k$ are the polynomials in $x$, so $\tilde f \in k[x]$. Also, $\tilde f$ has the property $\tilde f \cdot x = 1$, because this identity is true on the dense open subset $\mathbb A^1_k \setminus \{0\}$. But that cannot happen, because $x$ is not a unit in $k[x]$, which can be seen by realizing that $k[x] / (x) \cong k \neq 0$.